# Why does redis-cli DUMP (rdcli) return (nil) when the value passed is a loop control variable?

Tags: bash, shell, redis, redis-cli

My goal is to loop over a list of keys and generate a DUMP for each key

I am using `redis-cli` installed via `npm` which is why I call it as `rdcli`

```
# For reading comprehension:
export RED="rdcli -h $redis_endpoint -p $redis_port -a $redis_pass"

# This returns a list of my redis keys
$RED KEYS "*"
# The returned lines are numbered so I strip them off like so
$RED KEYS "*" | cut -d' ' -f2-

# This generates a file of serialized data which I can later pass to my new redis instance
$RED DUMP $key >> redis.dmp
```

This works fine when $key is a single key. However, if I attempt to loop over the list of redis keys

```
for key in $($RED KEYS "*" | cut -d' ' -f2-); do 
    $RED DUMP $key; 
done
```

or

```
$RED KEYS "*" | cut -d' ' -f2- | xargs -I key $RED DUMP key
```

or

```
# runfile.file contains fully expanded, hardcoded commands
# Ex:
# rdcli -h xxx -p yyy -a zzz DUMP :1:aaa
# rdcli -h xxx -p yyy -a zzz DUMP :1:bbb
# rdcli -h xxx -p yyy -a zzz DUMP :1:ccc
chmod +x runfile.file
./runfile.file
# this may be a separate issue but the symptoms are the same
```

Output:

```
(nil)
(nil)
(nil)
(nil)
...
```

My only hint is that enabling debug mode with `set -x` reveals that

```
$RED DUMP $key
# where $key is set during runtime
```

is being evaluated as

```
rdcli -h xxx -p yyy -a zzz DUMP ':1:aaa'
# and subsequently spitting out (nil)
```

If I copy and paste `rdcli -h xxx -p yyy -a zzz DUMP ':1:aaa'` back into the shell it correctly returns serialized code but I am unable to do this programatically.

Additional info:

- I have thousands of keys so I cannot do this by hand
- I am pulling the keys from a heroku redis instance and have no way to download a backup or save
- I am migrating to an Elasticache redis which prevents me from setting it up as a follower of the heroku instance as [these commands are restricted](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/RestrictedCommands.html)
- The two redis servers cannot communicate directly which is why I am using the DUMP and restore method

Comment: Put the variable in quotes: `$RED DUMP "$key"` if it can contain spaces.

Comment: For starters, `bash` has a `function` and `arrays` , so don't make it too [complex](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) Also there is a reason why you [DRLWF](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: @Barmar That does not work. `"$key"` is still evaluated with single quotes and therefore still returns `(nil)`